# Jquery function on object's property via this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

I have an object:

```
var obj = { id: $('#f_view') };
```

I have a function:

```
function switchFrom(trigger) {
          trigger.id.click(function() {
                 this.id.toggleClass('class');
          });
};
```

When i run the function:

```
switchFrom(obj);
```

I get :

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating'this.id.toggleClass('class')')
```

When I refer to the element explicitly, the function works.

```
$('#f_view').toggleClass('class');
```

What Am i doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `id` is a pretty bad variable name in your case. Should be something like `$ele`

Comment: `trigger.id.toggleClass('class');` is what you wanted to do. The answer below is probably better though

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar , this way works, thank you. I was just wondering whether same thing can be done with `this` reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert to a jQuery object by wrapping in `$(...)` like

```
function switchFrom(trigger) {
         trigger.id.click(function() {
                 $(this).toggleClass('class');
          });
}
```

This is because native javascript objects do not have access to jQuery methods

Comment: when i have the object set up like: `var obj = { id: $('#f_view') };` and I do:  `$(this).toggleClass('class'); ` I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove `.id` reference to the object's property. your solution works.

Comment: As a side note, if you want `this` inside function to refers to object, you need to `call()` method (or using `apply()`): http://jsfiddle.net/qz4odfj8/2/